# Index in space usage section in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am worried about this index. My file size is 25MB, when I export this to SQL, its file size grows to 57MB.

Does anyone have an idea about this index? and what are its disadvantages?

[image: MySQL - SpaceUsage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing. It is very possible that index(es) take more (or much more) than actual data.

You should revise which indexes you have and whether they are all really necessary and used by your queries, and drop ones that are not referred by anything.

It is typical newbie mistake when you create lots of indexes for every field - you can do that, but it will waste a lot of space needlessly.

While indexes do speed up searches, too many indexes may be expensive to upkeep, and make updates and inserts slower.

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantage of the index is the 33mb of extra space being used. However, indexes can significantly speed up queries as well as maintain data integrity by preventing duplicates.

[Wikipedia: Database index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)